# IF COUNTIF Unique Value + 1st duplicate

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I have basic question related with Excel 2016.
I have a huge table which displays names, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce9Jr.jpg)

For Column B "Helper" has been used below formula :

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1,"Unique","")
```

The formula is flagging all unique values, but I want to flag also the 1st duplicate row as well, as shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siXvv.jpg) .

I saw that formula on topic "How to get distinct values in Excel (unique + 1st duplicate occurrences)" :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$10), 0, 0), 0)), "")
```

But the formula is using duplicating list `INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,` and is not useful in my scenario due the fact I have millions rows.

In additional I need **one value**  for all unique + 1st duplicating row for latter calculations.
Unfortunately we are limited to Office 2016 and UNIQUE function from Office 365 cannot be used  :(

Sound quite simple, but I'm stuck from couple of hours, and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The function which I was searching has been found :) 
Please see below formula : 

=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$16,A3)>1,IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A3,A3)=1,"Unique",""),"Unique")

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)=1,"Unique","")`